# What does 2 declarations of `translate` keyword inside of CSS transform property mean? Ex: `transform: translate() translate()`

Tags: css, css-animations

I recently stumbled upon some CSS code using `transform` css property using 2 `translate` values inside of the `transform`. I am not sure exactly how to interpret this:

```css
transform: translate(-50%, -50%) translate(200px, 40px)`,
```

I had trouble finding any examples on the MDN docs or top hits on google.

Do the transforms override each other, are these like stacking values?

I've seen `transform` property used like this before:

```css
/* Function values */
.some-class {
  transform: translate(10px, 10px)
}
.some-class {
  transform: translateX(10px) 
}
.some-class {
  transform: translateY(10px) 
}
/* Multiple function values */
.some-class {
   transform: translateX(10px) rotate(10deg) translateY(5px);
}
```

#### References

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform
- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playdemo.php?filename=playcss_transform&preval=translate(20px,10px)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's one translation applied after another. In the case of `translate(-50%, -50%) translate(200px, 40px)`, it's first moving to `-50%` of the range, then after it reaches that position, it's offset by an additional `200px, 40px`.

You can stack CSS transforms like this. You can also easily test this in the MDN site you linked, by editing the translate example to add another one, and observe the behavior.